# CakePHP2 validation on field not in table

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.8

I have 4 attributes in a table; `num_a`, `num_b`, `num_c`, `num_d`, these individually can be in a range of 0 to 2, e.g. I have in my `$validate` property in model:

```
'num_a' => [
  'numeric' => [
    'rule' => 'numeric',
    'message' => 'Please provide the number of a.',
  ],
 'isInRange' => [
   'rule' => ['range', -1, 3],
   'message' => 'Must be between 0 and 2.'
 ],
```

The problem I am facing is that the sum of these must be greater than 0. I would like it to return some validation error if this is the case, e.g.:

```
'num_all' => [
  'rule' => 'returnFalse',
  'message' => 'There were no a, b, c or d selected.',
],
```

I have the `returnFalse` function in my model which is simply

```
public function returnFalse() {
  return false;
}
```

to always add this rule.

In the `beforeValidate` I am checking the sum of `num_a` through `num_d` and removing the validation rule if `$sum > 0` like so:

```
public function beforeValidate($options=array())
{
  $sum = 0;
  $sum += (isset($this->data['MyModel']['num_a'])) ? $this->data['MyModel']['num_a'] : 0;
  $sum += (isset($this->data['MyModel']['num_b'])) ? $this->data['MyModel']['num_b'] : 0;
  $sum += (isset($this->data['MyModel']['num_c'])) ? $this->data['MyModel']['num_c'] : 0;
  $sum += (isset($this->data['MyModel']['num_d'])) ? $this->data['MyModel']['num_d'] : 0;

  if ($sum > 0) {
    $this->validator()->remove('num_all');
  }
}
```

But for some reason I can not get this to return a validation error for `num_all`.

I even tried to add a virtual field so maybe the validation error had something to attach to:

```
public $virtualFields = [
  'num_all' => 'SELECT 0 FROM dual',
];
```

but this didn't work either. I am using CakePHP v2.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I ditched the `num_all` in the `$validate` property and the virtual field, etc. and the 'always fails' rule, and instead hacked on an entry to the models `validationErrors` array in `beforeValidate`:

```
public function beforeValidate($options=array())
{
  $sum = 0;
  $sum += (isset($this->data['MyModel']['num_a'])) ? $this->data['MyModel']['num_a'] : 0;
  $sum += (isset($this->data['MyModel']['num_b'])) ? $this->data['MyModel']['num_b'] : 0;
  $sum += (isset($this->data['MyModel']['num_c'])) ? $this->data['MyModel']['num_c'] : 0;
  $sum += (isset($this->data['MyModel']['num_d'])) ? $this->data['MyModel']['num_d'] : 0;

  if ($sum > 0) {
    $this->validationErrors['num_all'][] = 'There were no a, b, c or d selected.'
  }
}
```

And it works fine now. Hope this helps.